# Tensorflow's memory cost gradually increasing in very simple “for loop”

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a very strange problem on tensorflow. I simplified my question to the following version：

I ask this because I need run a series of training, I just put them in a for loop, then I use different parameters for each iteration.

To simplify the question,  I just write a simple Matrix multiplication in tensorflow language, then I put this "Matrix multiplication training" in a "for loop"(Of course you can put other complicated functions in the for loop, the conclusion is same).

I set 100000 iterations times，which means I will run 10000 training examples. and print the time-consuming in each loop, then I can observe that the consumption of time is same for each iteration, this is no problem. But the memory cost increase very quickly and finally I got the Error：“ run out of memory ”(what I expect is the memory should keep same for each iteration)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import datetime  

for i in range(100000):   # I must put the following code in this for loop
    starttime = datetime.datetime.now()
    graph=tf.Graph()
    with graph.as_default():  
        with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
            a=np.arange(100).reshape(1,-1)
            b=np.arange(10000).reshape(100,100)
            A = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1,100])
            B = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [100,100])

            sess = tf.InteractiveSession()


            RESULT =tf.matmul(A,B)





            RESULT_o=sess.run(RESULT,feed_dict={A: a, B: b})
    endtime = datetime.datetime.now()   
    print(endtime-starttime)
```

[image]

I know the reason is that in each iteration， the program created a new operation，this will increase memory. I want to know is there any way to release the memory cost after each iteration?      (this memory problem is same for GPU situation)

Comment: try ```import gc; gc.collect()``` after each 100 iterations or so.

Comment: That is not a problem. you are solving your requirement wrong. What you should be doing is creating one graph and feeding the data iteratively to it. you are creating new tf graph for each iteration. which is causing you to run out of memory fast. I would advice you to restructure your code.

Comment: This doesn't work, the memory still keep increasing.  
Is there any TensorFlow method for this problem？

Comment: I know what you means.  I just simplify my code into this version,  i have to put the training into a for loop,  it means  I have to run multiple training, my
  situation must do it in this way( for some special reason).  that's why I have to release memory,

Comment: tensorflow doesn't work that way. I understand you have a special case. Try and find a way how you can translate your special case to the standards. Try to look at the problem from a broader perspective. figure out how you can use this technique and solve the problem

Comment: OK,understand.  thank you very much

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code should be structured like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

A = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1,100])
B = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [100,100])
result = tf.matmul(A,B)

init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# Later, when launching the model
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Run the init operation. 
    # This will make sure that memory is only allocated for the variable once.
    sess.run(init_op)

    for i in range(100000):
        a = np.arange(100).reshape(1,-1)
        b = np.arange(10000).reshape(100,100)
        sess.run(result, feed_dict={A: a, B: b})
        if i % 1000 == 0:
            print(i, "processed")
```

Here you will allocate memory once for the first iteration and keep reusing the same memory block in successive iterations.

Comment: OK,understand.  thank you very much,I will try to revise the code.