# Why does memory usage increase as a Keras neural network is being trained with fit_generator and validation_data?

Tags: neural-network, keras

I have 32 GB of RAM and am training a large dataset using a Keras sequential neural network on a Windows 7 machine. Because of the size of the dataset, I have opted to use `fit_generator` taking in around 5000 samples in each batch which has about 500 features each. I have a `gc.collect()` in the generator to address the potential memory leak, which helped in previous iterations of this model.

For the first few steps of the first epoch, memory consumption is low. Then after around 15 steps, it starts to increase and decrease until eventually it caps off at 27.6 GB.

Can anyone explain why the memory usage increases over time? Also, its been hundreds of steps for this first epoch, and the memory is still sitting at 27.6 GB. Does this have any significance?

The NN itself is 3 layers deep, with 50 neurons in each. I understand that there are some memory requirements for storing the weights, but would this increase over time?

```python
def gen_data(max,rows,skip):
    import gc
    while True:
        data = pd.read_csv(csv,skiprows=range(1,skip),nrows=rows,index_col=0)
        x,y = features(data)
        yield x,y
        skip += rows
        if max is not None and skip >= max:
            skip = 0
        gc.collect()

model=Sequential()
model.add(Dense(50, input_dim = train_shape, activation='linear'))
model.add(LeakyReLU())
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(50, input_dim = train_shape, activation='linear'))
model.add(LeakyReLU())
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(50, input_dim = train_shape, activation='linear'))
model.add(LeakyReLU())
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')

hist = model.fit_generator(gen_data(8000000,5000),epochs=50,
             steps_per_epoch=int(8000000/5000),verbose=1,callbacks=callbacks_list,
       class_weight=class_weight,validation_steps=10,validation_data=gen_data(800000,80000))
```

-- edit --

When removing validation_steps and validation_data, the process does not blow up in memory. This seems like odd behavior because I would not expect the validation data to be used until the end of the epoch. Any ideas?

Comment: please share code.

Comment: Also this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44825360/tensorflows-memory-cost-gradually-increasing-in-very-simple-for-loop/44825824#44825824

Comment: An easy test to rule out the weights of the network is to cut out one layer. If the memory still sits close to 27 GB, the problem must be somewhere else. My money is on the `gen_data` function. You are loading data for each loop. That seems unnecessary.

Comment: In mode.fit_generator() you can add the patch size parameter so its computationally less expensive on your machine.